# How can I create subheaders for specific rows in a table?

Tags: flextable

In my dataset I have a grouping column that I would like to use to create subheaders for specific rows in a table.  Is it possible to create a table similar to the one below using Flexible where the subheader "Race" is for only for select rows ("White", "Black", "Hispanic" or "Latino", and "Asian") in this case?

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSj3S.png)